# Finding the mode of a MOSFET

Tags: mosfet, circuit-analysis, nmos

I'm trying to determine the state of MOSFET \$T_1\$ in the following circuit:

[image]

We are given that the threshold voltage \$V_\mathrm{T}\$ is \$1.5\ \mathrm{V}\$ and that every voltage source is \$5\ \mathrm{V}\$, except \$V_6\$ which is \$1\ \mathrm{V}\$.

I know \$T_1\$ is not in saturation mode, as
$$V_\mathrm{G1}=10\ \mathrm{V},\ V_\mathrm{D1}=5\ \mathrm{V}-I_\mathrm{D1}\cdot 1\ \mathrm{k\Omega},\ V_\mathrm{S1}=I_\mathrm{D1}\cdot 1\ \mathrm{k\Omega}-5\ \mathrm{V},$$
so that
$$V_\mathrm{GS1}-V_\mathrm{T}=13.5\ \mathrm{V}-I_\mathrm{D1}\cdot 1\ \mathrm{k\Omega} > 10\ \mathrm{V}-2I_\mathrm{D1} = V_\mathrm{DS1}$$

However, I can't determine whether it is in cutoff mode \$(V_\mathrm{GS}<V_\mathrm{T})\$, or triode mode \$(V_\mathrm{GS1}>V_\mathrm{T}\ \& \ V_\mathrm{DS1}<V_\mathrm{GS1}-V_\mathrm{T})\$

Any hints?

Comment: What are the values of V1, V2, V3, V4? All 5V? If so, the T1 will be in triode mode. Because 10V at the gate is larger than 5V at the drain.